# Which of the two code is better on memory basis?

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, textview

I am learning android development from a course by Udacity.While I was going through the Lesson 2,there came a situation where we had to create multiple Textviews,set the text from previously created `ArrayList` of strings and add those Textviews to Linear layout.

Common code:

```
 ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    words.add("one");
    words.add("two");
    words.add("three");
    words.add("four");
    words.add("five");
    words.add("six");
    words.add("seven");
    words.add("eight");
    words.add("nine");
    words.add("ten");
    LinearLayout rootView =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
```

Now what they did:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
TextView wordView=new TextView(this);
wordView.setText(words.get(i));
rootView.addView(wordView);
 }
```

What I did:

```
ArrayList<TextView> wordView = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        wordView.add(new TextView(this));
        wordView.get(i).setText(words.get(i));
        rootView.addView(wordView.get(i));


    }
```

Now,my question is weather my way to approach the task has more memory overheads than their way?

I feel my code is better because I have reference to each `TextView` even after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. In both cases `TextView` instances could not be garbage collected, so memory foot print is equal.

> because I have reference to each TextView even after the loop.

If you don't really need these references then it's just senseless. It's not memory related advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. But I don't see a point on having 10 the same TextViews. I would consider using a listView or recyclerView if you are using it as a list and thinking about optimising your code.

But still your code is fine.

Comment: `I would consider using a listView or recyclerView` But each row would be a single TextView, so... what optimization would that be? Moreover, you would have a ViewGroup in addition to the single rows.

Comment: ListViews are optimised for a displaying a list of items. So with memory the rows are reused.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter performance wise.. Just like you said:

> I feel my code is better because I have reference to each TextView even after the loop.

If you need that, do it..